# Elementor on wordpress: I need my product card button to open a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I copied product card from codepen.io and I don't really understand the code, but I managed to change up colors and stuff, but I can't make this button work.

This is product code:

```
<div class="card">

  <div class="imgBox">
    <img src="https://toppng.com/uploads/thumbnail/valorant-11608280122mrhwm6iwqx.png" alt="mouse corsair" class="mouse">
  </div>

  <div class="contentBox">
    <h3>Mouse Corsair M65</h3>
    <h2 class="price">61.<small>98</small> €</h2>
    <a href="#" class="buy">BRONEERI</a>
  </div>

</div>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Istok Web", sans-serif;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
}


.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #0f1923;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff4655;
  transform: skewY(345deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  top: -70%;
  transform: skewY(390deg);
}

.card::after {
  content: "CORSAIR";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 6em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card .imgBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
/*
.card .imgBox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    
    transition: .5s;
}

.card:hover .imgBox img {
    max-width: 50%;
      
}
*/
.card .contentBox {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card .contentBox h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card .contentBox .price {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card .contentBox .buy {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ff4655;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .contentBox .buy {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mouse {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
```

And this is link to what button should open:

```
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/mokez/neace?hide_gdpr_banner=1" style="min-width:320px;height:630px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>
```

Comment: You should pass link in ```href="link you want to open"``` rather than ```href="#"```.

Comment: Ooh, yea, but it's inline embed, so how can i make this work?

Comment: do you want to open the link `https://calendly.com/mokez/neace?hide_gdpr_banner=1` or to show the div with the `data-url` pointing to it?

Comment: Yea, i think so... i don't want link to open, it should pop out right there. @lolBOTV9.17

Comment: Is the domain this app is on the same as the domain you need to send a request to? Or, do you own both domains?

Comment: if not, then you may have a cors issue (iframe requests across domains is restricted)

Comment: It's not the same domain. and they aren't mine.

Comment: No, i got one button working, but i don't understand this "product code", that i copied and i can't make this one work.

Answer (score -1):

try using https://www.w3schools.com/ to learn html and js

```
<div class="card">

  <div class="imgBox">
    <img src="https://toppng.com/uploads/thumbnail/valorant-11608280122mrhwm6iwqx.png" alt="mouse corsair" class="mouse">
  </div>

  <div class="contentBox">
    <h3>Mouse Corsair M65</h3>
    <h2 class="price">61.<small>98</small> €</h2>
    <a href="#" class="buy" onclick='showelement()'>BRONEERI</a>
  </div>
<div id="showandhide" class="calendly-inline-widget"  style="min-width:320px;height:630px;display:none;"><iframe src='https://calendly.com/mokez/neace?hide_gdpr_banner=1'></iframe></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js" async></script>

</div>
<style>
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Istok Web", sans-serif;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
}


.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #0f1923;
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ff4655;
  transform: skewY(345deg);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  top: -70%;
  transform: skewY(390deg);
}

.card::after {
  content: "CORSAIR";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 6em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.card .imgBox {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
/*
.card .imgBox img {
    max-width: 100%;
    
    transition: .5s;
}

.card:hover .imgBox img {
    max-width: 50%;
      
}
*/
.card .contentBox {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 2;
}

.card .contentBox h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card .contentBox .price {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.card .contentBox .buy {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #ff4655;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card:hover .contentBox .buy {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mouse {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}
</style>
<script>
<script>
function showelement(){
if(document.querySelector('#showandhide').style.display==="none"){
document.querySelector('#showandhide').style.display="block"
} else {
document.querySelector('#showandhide').style.display==="none"
}
}
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: It might work, but i don't understand how to add it to my code :D

Comment: here, I edited my answer so that the code is in your html already.

Comment: The problem is that you are requesting another domain by way of iframe unless you are the host of 'calenderly'. This would not work unless the application you are requesting has the correct cross-origin resource sharing settings to allow your site to access it.

Comment: True, but there isn't any other way to do it...

Comment: I mean, I'm sure that calendly **_has_** the proper cors settings, or clients would have trouble using it.